# PHP is_writable always false on NFS

Tags: php7, nfs4

Sorry, I'm not sure, if this is the correct forum because I don't know the cause for the issue, I'm facing.

I installed NextCloud on a Raspbian (Stretch 9) and moved the data directory to a mounted NFS folder.
When I try to access NextCloud, I got the error message *'Data directory is not writable'*.

So I dug a better deeper and could finally isolate the issue to the interaction between PHP7.0 and the NFS:

For some reason, the application **can** write to the directory **but** is_writable returns `false`.

I have created the following PHP script:

```
<?php
$dirname = '/var/churros/data/nextcloud/';
//$dirname = '/tmp/';

$myfile = fopen($dirname.'newfile.txt', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
echo nl2br("File ".$dirname."newfile.txt written\n");

if (touch($dirname.'/chkpt.tmp')) {
   echo nl2br("touch(".$dirname."/chkpt.tmp) successful\n");
} else {
   echo nl2br("touch(".$dirname."/chkpt.tmp) failed\n");
}

if (is_writable($dirname)) {
        echo 'Directory '.$dirname.' is writable';
} else {
        echo 'Directory '.$dirname.' is not writable';
}

phpinfo();
?>
```

The result is that

- newfile.txt is created in the data directory with the given text (*John Doe*)
- Touch succeeded, i.e. the checkpoint file is created
- `is_writable` returns false
  [Screenshot of 'debug.php' with NFS directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp6jM.png)

When I change to directory to a local directory like `\tmp` everything is fine
[Screenshot of 'debug.php' with /tmp directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZOMr.png)

My NFS is mounted as

```
192.168.1.100:/volume1/pidata/donut on /var/churros type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.103,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.100)
```

and obviously the user mapping and access rights are correct:

```
namei -l /var/churros/web/nextcloud/
f: /var/churros/web/nextcloud/
drwxr-xr-x root     root     /
drwxr-xr-x root     root     var
drwxr-xr-x root     root     churros
drwxr-xr-x www-data www-data web
drwxrwxr-x www-data www-data nextcloud
```

Finally, on the command line, as user www-data, I can access the directory and write to it as well.

So: Any idea why PHP `is_writable` fails on the NFS directory?

Comment: PHP sometimes operates as `nobody` instead of the web server user (`www`, `apache`, `www-data`, etc). It's possible that could be causing he method to return `false`.

Comment: @JustinPearce - thanks, yeah that's what I thought as well but when I printed the user running PHP with `$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid()); print $processUser['name'];`, it shows `www-data`

Comment: PHP 7.0 no longer receives bug fixes. Update to PHP 7.1 (Nextcloud doesn't yet support 7.2). I also have Nextcloud storing data on an NFS server and have no issues.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you state

```
$dirname = '/var/churros/data/nextcloud/';
```

However, when you demonstrate permissions below, you show

```
namei -l /var/churros/web/nextcloud/
```

How do we know that dir *data* is properly writable?

what is the result of:

```
namei -l /var/churros/data/nextcloud/
```

### ???

Also, I'm curious how

```
if (touch($dirname.'/chkpt.tmp')) {...
```

worked in the above script, it should have acted on /var/churros/data/nextcloud//chkpt.tmp (note double-slash between dir: nextcloud and filename chkpt.tmp).

I have occasionally included typos... and even typo'd scripts instead of copying/pasting exactly as is... My point is, at first glance it appears there are inconsistencies in the OP that are either contributing to the error while meeting certain conditions coincidentally, or very simply the first variable declaration needs to be modified to read .../web/nextcloud/ to meet the actual dir requirements as stated...